# Why do I have to deploy twice for changes in asset pipeline to be picked up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

Here is my (censored) config/deploy.rb:
https://gist.github.com/eedf6c976f632c1242cf

For some reason, any changes to my assets, whether CoffeeScript or SASS/SCSS files, do not appear in production when I first deploy. When I deploy a second time, the assets changes go live. It's quite a waste of time, and I have no idea why it's happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated but it looks like you mixed your unicorn tasks into your deploy namespace. You're also doing a full unicorn stop and start on each deploy when you should just be doing a reload. Can you paste your terminal output when you run a deploy?

Comment: Here it is (censored): https://gist.github.com/cfb8312db767806fe7a4

Comment: The "invalid date format in specification" is also annoying, but unrelated and not critical.

Comment: Another somewhat unrelated comment, but you should add `set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false` to your deploy file to get rid of the touch command on the public directory. (The "no such file or directory" messages) So when you do a deploy, are the new js/css files actually compiled but your app references the older ones? Or are the new js/css files not compiled at all?

Comment: Okay, I just made a change to my stylesheet and ran the deploy twice. Each time I checked the `shared/assets` directory for the change. The first time, the new stylesheet complete with the new MD5 hash was not present. It also did not appear in `manifest.yml` or in the rendered pages. I then deployed a second time without any changes. This time, there was a new stylesheet with a new MD5 hash in the `shared/assets` directory, and it was present in both `manifest.yml` and the rendered pages.

Comment: So it looks like the new changes are not resulting in new files from the precompilation task during the first deploy, even though the task runs both times. I can post a Gist of both `cap deploy` outputs if you'd like.

Comment: What files are modified by your `symlink_shared` task?

Comment: Currently that task doesn't do anything; it has one line which is commented out.

Comment: Any more info on this? Still happening, and not just in one project. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to get it working, but it isn't clean. For some reason, `deploy:assets:precompile` is being run just before `deploy:create_symlink`, rather than after. The result is that the `current` directory on the server is not yet pointing at the new code when assets are being compiled, so they're only compiling for the previous deploy. This is why my assets were not updating unless I deployed twice.

I applied a quick-fix by adding this:

`before "deploy:assets:precompile", "deploy:create_symlink"`

This triggers the creating the symlink just before precompiling so that asset changes are picked up. The result is that the symlink is created twice, because the existing behavior is also still run. It works, but it feels dirty.

I'm really not sure why this is an issue in the first place, and I don't understand why nobody else seems to be having this issue; my `deploy.rb` is pretty cut-and-dry, nothing too fancy going on. The only thing I can think of is that `load "deploy/assets"` isn't in the right place in the file. I just assumed it went at the top, and I don't know if it affects the order of execution.

Any suggestions as the the correct way to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your Capfile looks like this:

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

Just swap the placement of `deploy/assets` and `config/deploy`. So:

```
load 'deploy'
load 'config/deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
```

Answer (score 0):

I caught the same error when I use this gem.

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

When I use the gem below everything is ok~~

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```

Notice: do not use both the two gems or you could meet deploying step of each gem overrite.

In my experience, U should deploy, see the process and output in your console, detect what's wrong.

Maybe your before... and after... command cannot work.